# Show causing sql query in stacktrace of org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

i have been looking at the stacktrace of `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException` to find out the causing SQL query or table where it happens. However, my attempts were futile (without debugging), because all i see is the following:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
...
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncated for column 'category' at row 1
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for column 'category' at row 1
...
```

Nevertheless, if i set a conditional breakpoint for the `GenericJDBCException` and debug into the code, i noticed, that the `GenericJDBCException` actually has a field called sql which shows me the table/sql involved in the error.

In my case, that was `update config_OptionRef set category=?, fk_option=?, refKey=? where id=?`, so now i know at least the corresponding table name.

Hence the question. Is it possible to have hibernate to display this info in the stacktrace?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think you can do it in the stacktrace but you can set the org.hibernate.SQL logger for hibernate sql to trace, and if you need the parameters as well, the logger is org.hibernate.type. But that will print EVERY sql query, which might not be exactly what you want :/

Comment: exactly, i don't want every query, but just the one causing the error. it is beyond me, why it does not show up in stack trace since all of the information is actually there ...

Comment: if you look into SqlExceptionHelper from hibernate there's a logger there that when in debug it logs the sql, maybe you can try that